# Display all product images instead of carousel in product detail - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images

How can i display all product images in product detail page? I need to display all products images at the same time (no carousel) and mantain magnifier zoom functionalities qnd Swatch image change options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below function on product object

```
   $images =  $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

you will receive a collection of images in $images

Comment: Yes it works thanks but there is not a simple way to mantain magnifier zoom functionalities?

Comment: Now please tick my ans

Comment: but i need to mantain magnifier zoom functionalities, i have updete my question. if no one get a better unswer i will tick your thanks a lot

Comment: Well i am not a frontend guy who is in more on design. You should check this one https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery_mg.html This will help you to use it.

Comment: but is it possible there is no a simple way to display all images instead of carousel without rewrite all code? it's seems to be strange.